# How to access Microsoft Graph Api using Jenkins for automation

Tags: jenkins, microsoft-graph-api, ui-automation, cicd, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have recently migrated my test automation project from using smtp protocols to Microsoft Graph Api to automate sending emails and reading the replies. We are getting the access token using ClientSecretCredentialBuilder and we are able to send the emails and read the replies when run locally, however when the same tests are run through jenkins we are facing 404 : Not Found error when trying to send emails.

The Azure app is having all the required permissions to send and read the emails, am I missing anything in the permissions or do I have to install any Jenkins plugin to read the data from Microsoft Graph API services?

Below is the error that I am facing:

com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ResourceNotFound
Error message: Resource could not be discovered.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1/microsoft.graph.sendMail
SdkVersion : graph-java/v3.2.0
[...]

404 : Not Found
[...]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is working locally, I guess the problem lies on the `Id` of the user you are using.

Is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1/microsoft.graph.sendMail` copy and pasted or did you changed the `Id` before posting it here for security reasons? If you didn't change the url, this should be the issue because you will not have a user with `Id: 1`. Most of the time, the `Id` will be a GUID, read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryobject?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Another possibility would be that you are saving the `Id` of the user you need for testing in an environment variable and you forgot to add this variable in Jenkins.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to add the environment variable in Jenkins. It worked after adding the variable. Thanks :)